# How to pass command line argument in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

I have two ipynb files,

cmd.ipynb

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

test.ipynb

```
%run cmd.ipynb 1 2 3 4
```

When runnng test.ipynb, I was hoping it can print

```
['cmd.ipynb', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

, but instead it printed out

```
['.../python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py', '-f', '.../.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-fd79e9d9-d66f-4cf6-856b-a4a3c3ea73a0.json']
```

Can anyone tell me how to address that?

Comment: does it need to be a python notebook file? If you rename it to `.py` it runs just fine: `%run cmd.py 1 2 3 4` prints `['cmd.py', '1', '2', '3', '4']`

Comment: That's because a `.ipynb` file is not a `.py` file. An `.ipynb` comes with its own quirks (its own arguments) and that's why you see what you see when you `%run cmd.ipynb`. Your best bet would be to put the code in a `cmd.py` file and `%run cmd.py 1 2 3 4` instead.

Comment: From [the docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html).: *There is one special usage for which the text above doesn’t apply: if the filename ends with .ipy[nb], the file is run as ipython script, just as if the commands were written on IPython prompt.*. `.ipy[nb]` files get special treatment. Rename as suggested.

Comment: Thank for your help! I've got another issue. Assume that I want to pass a variable as a command line argument, how can I use the value of that variable instead of using the name of that variable?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please post new questions as new questions, not as ride along comments to existing, different questions.